# Why is the height of DIVs containing images inflated by 4.5px?

Tags: css, html, height

This div will have a computed height of 104.5px (in most recent Chrome, FF, and IE)

```
<div><img src="" height="100px" /></div>
```

This div will have a computed height of 100px

```
<div style="overflow:auto;"><img src="" height="100px" style="float:left;" /></div>
```

I used FireBug to look at the DIVs and IMGs, and both IMGs have 0 for margin, padding, and border, yet the computed height somehow is 4.5px bigger in the first instance.

Why is this? It impacts me when I try to layout a page with a consistent vertical grid. Ideally, I'd like to not have to float the imgs.

I tried to look here ==> http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.7.2 and I even tried vspace=0, but that didn't change anything.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Rendered as 100px height for both on my FF3.6. Do you have any other styles that might have caused the problem?

Comment: Is there any padding or margin applied to the div?

Comment: No other syles are applied. I removed the stylesheet and just used the code I provided. So no padding or margin applied to the DIV and no external style sheet is used.

O.K.W - calculated height in the box model was 100px for the first example?

Comment: @Peter, I don't know this is the problem, but you should not include `px` in an img attribute. It is simply, `<img src="" height="100" />`

Comment: @Doug Thanks for the info. What is your source? Using px for units validates in XHTML 1.0 strict (as does using no units, or em, pt, or %). I like to include px for my own reference, since sometimes I use em or %, so including the units keeps things clear.

Comment: @Peter, I can almost swear I ran into issues with browser bugs when I have used "100px" in the past, but as I just searched, it doesn't appear the documentation supports my suggestion! Maybe back in my `table` days it was a problem... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clients include their own stylesheets that should be overidden before you try to do any pixel-perfect layouts or cross-browser debugging. Even if you remove all your stylesheets there are still styles on the page.

Try it again with a css reset at the top of your stylesheet. Also, make sure that you're declaring a valid doctype. Use a strict doctype and make sure your code validates if that still doesn't help.

I usually use the meyer web reset with a few minor modifications that suit my workflow.

If other people are seeing 100px then it's likely a client side problem, so hopefully this troubleshoots it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Yahoo! CSS Reset](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) to get my browsers all starting from scratch, usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

Look out for a line-height definition at a high level when applied to a div that only contains an image.  (for example `html {line-height:1.5em;}`)

You probably still want this line height setting in general for resetting text throughout the site, but try applying `line-height:0` just to the div with nothing but an img inside it.

http://jsfiddle.net/kq3Yy/

Answer (score 0):

Setting `<div style="display:inline" />` should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There must be more going on here than what you show. How are you measuring these half pixels? What tool are you using? I can see line-height coming into play but you don't show that in your sample.

Comment: Like I said, I used FireBug to measure the calculated height of the div. If I add a background image with evenly spaced lines, I can also see this happens when I stack multiple instances of the first div one on top of the other. I didn't set line height, there are no other styles set besides the one in the example.